# bar color of the piechart not display in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pie-chart

hello i am new in angularjs following is my code of the html.

```
<div class="circular-bar" ng-repeat="cat1 in ['15']">
     <div class="chart" data-percent="{{cat1}}" data-bar-color="#e75200">              
          </div>
      </div>
```

in the above code pie chart bar color display fine but  in the below code bar color not display.here categorydata is the object which is dynamically come from the database.here data display properly  bar also display but barfilled color not display in below code.

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in categorydata">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <!--circular-bar-->

        <div class="circular-bar">

            <div class="chart" data-percent="{{cat.offers.length}}" data-bar-color="#e75200" chart1>
                <label><span class="percent">{{cat.offers.length}}</span></label>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="offerssub clr1">
            <h3>{{cat.name}}</h3>
            <h4>Redeemed</h4>
            <span>0</span>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

here is my angularjs directive.

```
app.directive('chart1', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'AEC',
     scope: {
       data: '=',
       categorydata:'=categorydata'
     },
     link: function(elem, attr) {
       $(function() {
         //jQuery(elem).bar
          jQuery('.chart').easyPieChart({
               lineWidth:35,
               scaleColor:false,
               size:330,
               lineCap: 'square',

           });
       });
     }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set only timeout in your directive that will help you to display pie chart after populating your data.

please follow below code when you use any jquery chart in angularjs at that time use timeout.

```
app.directive('chart1', function() {
  return {
  //   restrict: 'A',
    /* scope: {
       data: '=',
       categorydata:'=categorydata'
     },*/
     link: function(elem, attr) {
       $(function() {
         //jQuery(elem).bar
         setTimeout(function () {
           jQuery('.chart').easyPieChart({
                lineWidth:35,
                scaleColor:false,
                size:330,
                lineCap: 'square',

            });
         }, 200);
       });
     }
  }
})
```